# Is it possible to build completelly static Qt Creator on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static

I try to build static version of Qt without shared libraries at all. Is it possible to build completely static Qt Creator?
I built static Qt 5.4.1. However, when I try to build Qt Creator from source with it, I receive an error when it builds `libqbs_cpp_scanner.so`:

```
libstdc++.a(bad_alloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTVSt9bad_alloc' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I think the reason of this problem is conflict between the fact that I use completelly static Qt that refers to static standard C++ library and shared object. However, I don't see how to avoid shared object building.
Is it possible to build Qt Creator on Linux with static Qt? And if yes, how to bypass the error I receive? May be it is possible to skip libqbs_cpp_scanner.so building if this shared object is optional, or force this shared object to become static library?

Comment: just install qtcreator from synaptic or a package manager or anyway you like. Then add your static QT5.4.1 installation as a "kit" from settings. Then any project you build using that "kit" will be a static one which doesn't depend on any qt libs.

Comment: @jack_black You right it is the best idea, I tried a lot, really there are no need in static Qt creator, because official Linux build allows to add custom static Qt and even better, because I use faster shared builds during debug and slow, but independent static build for release.